# Firewall may be conflicting with VPN service

Tags: vpn

I have Eset Smart Security 5 and whenever I first start my computer it asks if the network I'm connected to is at home or public, as if it were the first time connecting the network. This started happening since I connect through VPN. The very first time I restarted my computer after getting VPN, Eset and Windows asked me what kind of network I'm connected to (Windows stopped after the first time). Is there something I should do to my Firewall now that I've got a VPN? I believe the VPN connects to different servers at differnt times (it's a VPN all my traffic goes throug).

Comment: This would probably be better suited to SuperUser, since it's a consumer software issue rather than a question about security. I've flagged for a mod to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If your VPN service is constantly connecting you to different servers (IP addresses) then your firewall is going to treat them all as separate connections.

It would be best to contact your VPN provider and ask them for the range of IP addresses they are using so you can add a permanent exception in your firewall. Then you could allow a range/block of IP addresses that your VPN provider uses (eg. 202.110.1.0 /24).